# Automatically submit an "OK" button press to SQL Server when brought up

Tags: c#, sql-server-2016

I'm opening an instance of MS SQL Server 2016 with a small C# program.

---

- When it comes up for the first time, there is a login box where
  essentially it asks for your username and password.
- This information is retained in the box because I clicked the
  "Remember Password" checkbox that is located on the box.
- Then to move on there is a "Connect" button you have to click to
  enter the application.

---

**My question is this:**
Is there any way possible using C# to "click" the connect button automatically so it goes into the application without me having to manually intervene and click the connect button?

---

Any help given will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Ssms command line argument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162825.aspx) should work here, but you need to specify the login credential in the argument.

```
Ssms -U [USERNAME] -P [PASSWORD] -S [SERVERNAME] -d [DBNAME] -nosplash
```